# Make axios returning response directly instead of AxiosResponse wrapper?

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

Can we make `axios` returning the `Puppy[]` response directly instead of `AxiosResponse<Puppy[]>` and having `.then(response => response.data)`?

```
const fetchKittens = (): Promise<Kitten[]> => axios.get<Kitten[]>('/kittens')
  .then(response => response.data);

// axios magic ‍

const fetchPuppies = (): Promise<Puppy[]> => axios.get<Puppy[]>('/puppies');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Axios request methods always return promises. There is no option to make synchronous HTTP requests (which are appalling for performance).

Comment: I'm not thinking about making synchronous calls, but skpping the `AxiosResponse` wrapper. I have 20+ request methods that have to invoke dummy `.then(response => response.data)`.
I'm wondering if making some global transformer applied to the `axios` instance may do the job here.

Comment: there is no getting around axios returning promises, but you can use async/await syntax to make it more tolerable.                                                                                        let result = await axios.get

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrap function, this function will call a request and just return `data`

```
const wrapAxiosResponse = async <T>(
  action: ReturnType<typeof axios.get> | ReturnType<typeof axios.post> // type of your request list
): Promise<T> => {
  let response = await action;
  return response.data as T;
}
```

How to use

```
const fetchKittens = (): Promise<Kitten[]> => wrapAxiosResponse(axios.get('/kittens'));
```

then,

```
fetchKittens().then(data => console.log(data)); // data relates to `response.data`
```

or `async/await` systax

`const data = await fetchKittens();`